# Basic CSS Code Works on Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

www.prismasites.com

The Pricing Section:

The DIV Boxes for The 3 Pricing Plans show in normal size using chrome but appear extremely tiny using Firefox.

Here is my DIV Code

```css
    #Pricing {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      background: #CEC8B6;
      position: relative;
      border: 0px solid black;
      top: 0px;
    }
    #PricingHeader1 {
      height: 5vh; width: 100%; background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/DollarBorderTop.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0px solid black; z-index: 999; }
      #PricingInfo {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 9%;
        width: 95%;
        top: 6%;
        border: 0px solid green;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #PricingBoxContainer {
        height: 65vh;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 8%;
        border: 0px solid green;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .PricingBoxContainers {
        height: 65vh;
        width: calc(100% / 3);
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        top: 0%;
        border: 0px solid orange;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #PricingBox1000Margin {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: table;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0px solid black;
        z-index: 999;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #PricingBox1000 {
        height: 90%;
        width: 90%;
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0px solid black;
        z-index: 999;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #PricingBox1700 {
        height: 100%;
        width: 90%;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0px solid black;
        z-index: 999;
      }
      #PricingBox2500 {
        height: 100%;
        width: 90%;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        right: 1.5%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0px solid black;
        z-index: 999;
      }
      #PB1000TLCorner {
        height: 5%; width: 5%; position: relative; display: inline-block; border: 0px solid green; background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/Pricing/TLCorner.png"); background-size: 100% 100%;   box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  }
        #PB1000TMBorder {
          height: 5%; width: 90%; position: relative; display: inline-block; border: 0px solid green; background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/Pricing/TBorder.png"); background-size: 100% 100%;  box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  }
          #PB1000TRCorner {
            height: 5%; width: 5%; position: relative; display: inline-block; border: 0px solid green;  background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/Pricing/TRCorner.png"); background-size: 100% 100%;   box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  }
            #PB1000MLBorder {
              height: 90%; width: 5%; position: relative; display: inline-block; border: 0px solid green; background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/Pricing/LBorder.png"); background-size: 100% 100%;  box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  }
              #PB1000Containr {
                vertical-align: top;
                height: 90%;
                width: 90%;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                top: 0%;
                border: 0px solid green;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              }
              #Pricing1000Title {
                height: 7.5%;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid black;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              }
              #Pricing1000Price {
                height: 7.5%;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid black;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              }
              #Pricing1000InfoContainer {
                height: 70%;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid black;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              }
              #Pricing1000Services {
                vertical-align: top;
                height: 100%;
                width: 50%;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid black;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              }
              #Pricing1000Payments {
                vertical-align: top;
                height: 100%;
                width: 50%;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid black;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              }
              #Pricing1000SummaryContainer {
                height: 15%;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid black;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              }
              #PB1000MRBorder {
                height: 90%; width: 5%; position: relative; display: inline-block; border: 0px solid green; background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/Pricing/LBorder.png"); background-size: 100% 100%; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);-o-transform: scaleX(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); transform: scaleX(-1); filter: FlipH; -ms-filter: "FlipH"; }
                #PB1000BLCorner {
                  height: 5%; width: 5%; position: relative; display: inline-block; border: 0px solid green; background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/Pricing/TLCorner.png"); background-size: 100% 100%; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);-o-transform: scaleY(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1); transform: scaleY(-1); filter: FlipV; -ms-filter: "FlipV"; }
                  #PB1000BMBorder {
                    height: 5%; width: 90%; position: relative; display: inline-block; border: 0px solid green; background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/Pricing/TBorder.png"); background-size: 100% 100%; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);-o-transform: scaleY(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1); transform: scaleY(-1); filter: FlipV; -ms-filter: "FlipV"; }
                    #PB1000BRCorner {
                      height: 5%; width: 5%; position: relative; display: inline-block; border: 0px solid green; background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/Pricing/TRCorner.png"); background-size: 100% 100%; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);-o-transform: scaleY(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1); transform: scaleY(-1); filter: FlipV; -ms-filter: "FlipV"; }
                      #PricingDisclaimer {
                        height: 9%;
                        width: 95%;
                        top: 10%;
                        border: 0px solid green;
                        position: relative;
                        font-size: 75%;
                        margin: auto;
                        overflow: hidden;
                      }
                      .PricingServices {
                        color: #006838;
                      }
                      #PricingHeader2 {
                        height: 5vh;
                        width: 100%;
                        background-image: url("http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/images/DolarBorder1.jpg");
                        background-size: 100% 100%;
                        position: absolute;
                        bottom: 0px;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                        border: 0px solid black;
                        z-index: 999;
                      }
```

```html
<div id="Pricing">
  <div id="PricingHeader1"></div>

  <div id="PricingInfo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla tempus semper. Nam ut gravida odio. Morbi feugiat iaculis nisl, tincidunt congue arcu sagittis id. Duis fermentum mauris ut justo malesuada auctor. Nullam aliquam sit amet ante sit
    amet rhoncus. Suspendisse varius ultricies facilisis. Ut auctor ligula pretium dapibus vestibulum. Sed ac libero auctor, consectetur sapien nec, laoreet lacus. Sed porta est nec massa luctus, eget mollis magna malesuada. Sed pharetra convallis turpis,
    vel eleifend orci lacinia non. Ut mi lacus, accumsan eget arcu porttitor, viverra pellentesque quam.</div>

  <div id="PricingBoxContainer">
    <div class="PricingBoxContainers">
      <div id="PricingBox1000Margin">
        <div id="PricingBox1000">
          <div id="PB1000TLCorner"></div>
          <div id="PB1000TMBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000TRCorner"></div>
          <div id="PB1000MLBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000Containr">
            <div id="Pricing1000Title"></div>
            <div id="Pricing1000Price"></div>
            <div id="Pricing1000InfoContainer">
              <div id="Pricing1000Services"></div>
              <div id="Pricing1000Payments"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="Pricing1000SummaryContainer"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="PB1000MRBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000BLCorner"></div>
          <div id="PB1000BMBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000BRCorner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="PricingBoxContainers">
      <div id="PricingBox1000Margin">
        <div id="PricingBox1000">
          <div id="PB1000TLCorner"></div>
          <div id="PB1000TMBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000TRCorner"></div>
          <div id="PB1000MLBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000Containr">
            <div id="Pricing1000Title"></div>
            <div id="Pricing1000Price"></div>
            <div id="Pricing1000InfoContainer">
              <div id="Pricing1000Services"></div>
              <div id="Pricing1000Payments"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="Pricing1000SummaryContainer"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="PB1000MRBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000BLCorner"></div>
          <div id="PB1000BMBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000BRCorner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="PricingBoxContainers">
      <div id="PricingBox1000Margin">
        <div id="PricingBox1000">
          <div id="PB1000TLCorner"></div>
          <div id="PB1000TMBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000TRCorner"></div>
          <div id="PB1000MLBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000Containr">
            <div id="Pricing1000Title"></div>
            <div id="Pricing1000Price"></div>
            <div id="Pricing1000InfoContainer">
              <div id="Pricing1000Services"></div>
              <div id="Pricing1000Payments"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="Pricing1000SummaryContainer"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="PB1000MRBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000BLCorner"></div>
          <div id="PB1000BMBorder"></div>
          <div id="PB1000BRCorner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="PricingDisclaimer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla tempus semper. Nam ut gravida odio. Morbi feugiat iaculis nisl, tincidunt congue arcu sagittis id. Duis fermentum mauris ut justo malesuada auctor. Nullam aliquam sit amet ante sit
    amet rhoncus. Suspendisse varius ultricies facilisis. Ut auctor ligula pretium dapibus vestibulum. Sed ac libero auctor, consectetur sapien nec, laoreet lacus. Sed porta est nec massa luctus, eget mollis magna malesuada. Sed pharetra convallis turpis,
    vel eleifend orci lacinia non. Ut mi lacus, accumsan eget arcu porttitor, viverra pellentesque quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla tempus semper. Nam ut gravida odio. Morbi feugiat iaculis nisl, tincidunt congue
    arcu sagittis id. Duis fermentum mauris ut justo malesuada auctor. Nullam aliquam sit amet ante sit amet rhoncus. Suspendisse varius ultricies facilisis. Ut auctor ligula pretium dapibus vestibulum. Sed ac libero auctor, consectetur sapien nec, laoreet
    lacus. Sed porta est nec massa luctus, eget mollis magna malesuada. Sed pharetra convallis turpis, vel eleifend orci lacinia non. Ut mi lacus, accumsan eget arcu porttitor, viverra pellentesque quam.
  </div>
  <div id="PricingHeader2"></div>
</div>
```

How come it works on one browser but not the other?
How can I get it to work on both browsers?

Comment: Those appear the same in my Firefox, which version do you have? I suggest that you compress the images or use smaller ones, or use photoshop and save them as web images, or something else because those are huge for web. UPDATE, now I see the difference, looking at what could it be.

Comment: Just answered below. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `display: table-cell;` at the `#PricingBox1000`.

Comment: It would be good to say at least "thank you for the time you spent" instead of using the solution someone provides without thanking or vote. Anyways I'm glad to see you solved it in the production website.